# Disable DirectorySlash for a single folder in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htaccess to redirect a bunch of URIs to remove trailing slashes and serving the homepage of a particular website I am working on, using the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine ON

# for homepage section URIs, redirect to remove trailing slash
RedirectMatch 301 ^(/?)(hero|night|entertainment|ticket-info|sponsors|charities|work|committee)/$ $1$2

# serve homepage
RewriteRule ^/?(hero|night|entertainment|ticket-info|sponsors|charities|work|committee)$ index.html [L]
```

However, there is also a folder called `ticket-info` and I want to be able to serve files from there eg /ticket-info/img.jpg or /ticket-info/buy/

Apache is automatically adding in the trailing slash and attempting to serve the directory index. I want to disable this behavior only for the /ticket-info and /ticket-info/ routes (but maintain the default behavior for any other files in that directory and for the rest of the website). I attempted to do this by adding the following rule but it is returning an internal server error.

```
# don't add slash even if directory exists
<Location /ticket-info/>
    DirectorySlash Off
    SetHandler some-handler
</Location>
```

What rules do I need to add to disable the adding of the slash for only this route, but keep the default behavior everywhere else?

Comment: you wouldn't, but I don't want any solution to prevent me serving such files

Comment: ticket-info isn't a directory right? If it's not, then mod_dir isn't the one adding the trailing slash

Comment: @JonLin it is a directory - that is the problem "there is also a folder called ticket-info and I want to be able to serve files from there"

Comment: @anubhava that's good, but my current rules need to change

Comment: "Apache is automatically adding in the trailing slash and attempting to serve the directory index. I want to disable this behavior only for the /ticket-info and /ticket-info/ routes"

... whilst keeping it for all other routes, if a directory of the same name exists

Comment: perhaps you could run a test and prevent this behaviour if there is no directory index, although I imagine testing the name is easier

Answer (score 1):

If `/ticket-info` is a directory, create an htaccess file there with this in it:

```
DirectorySlash off
SetHandler some-handler
```

You can't use the `<Location>` container in an htaccess file: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#location

Comment: this works for the redirection issue, however, if I create a subdirectory in /ticket-info/ eg /ticket-info/new then redirection doesn't occur

Comment: I tried creating .htaccess in /new and turning DirectorySlash back on. This appeared to work, but it won't take the user to the directory index.

Comment: I then tried adding `DirectoryIndex index.php index.html` to that .htaccess file as well, but that still didn't work.

Comment: @JoshBambrick in apache, if a directory is missing the trailing slash, it will NEVER show the directory index, and will ALWAYS show the directory contents.

Comment: Yes, but the trailing slash is added back in by DirectorySlash (in the `new` subdirectory). However, I am still getting a 404

Comment: Current setup.

root folder (htaccess contains rewriting rules for /hero|night|entertainment|ticket-info|sponsors|charities|work|committee)
|
|_ticket-info (htaccess turns off DirectorySlash)
  |
  |_new (htaccess turns on DirectorySlash and I tried adding DirectoryIndex rules)

Current behaviour:
/ticket-info redirection to homepage (good)
/ticket-info/new redirects to /ticket-info/new/ (good)
/ticket-info/new doesn't serve directory index (bad)

Comment: all the new lines were removed above but the issue is that /ticket-info/new/ isn't serving /ticket-info/new/index.html

Comment: DirectorySlash Off will turn DirectoryIndex off, but it DirectorySlash should be turned back on (the rule precedes the DirectoryIndex rule in `new`'s .htaccess file)

Comment: unsurprisingly, removing the `DirectorySlash off` rule from `ticket-info`'s .htaccess will re-enable the serving of `new`'s directory index